# Словарь внутри массива

Tags: python

Как я могу достать значение ключа из словаря, который находится в массиве?

```
w = [{'name':'alex', 'age':'39'}, {'name':'max', 'age':'25'}]
print 'alex' in w[0]
```

Comment: Можно сразу сказать: откуда бы вы не взяли словарь: из списка, из другого словаря, из функции вернули, в исходном коде из константы—получить значение по ключу всегда можно совершенно одинаково: `d[key]`. Происхождение словаря никакой роли не играет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
w = [{'name':'alex', 'age':'39'}, {'name':'max', 'age':'25'}]

print(w[0]['name'])
```

Чтобы перебрать все ключи

```
w = [{'name':'alex', 'age':'39'}, {'name':'max', 'age':'25'}]

for i in w:
    for key in i:
        print(key)
```

Чтобы работать со словарями по отдельности

```
w = [{'name':'alex', 'age':'39'}, {'name':'max', 'age':'25'}]

for i in w: #  в переменной i словарь
    if i['name'] == 'alex':
        print('alex')
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Comment: А как я могу пройтись по всему массиву для поиска имени в словаре с for?

Comment: @roman `w = [{'name':'alex', 'age':'39'}, {'name':'max', 'age':'25'}]

for i in w:
    for key in i:
        print(key)`

Comment: Странно выдает false

Comment: @roman возможно, не верно отформатировали код, я в ответ его вставил

Comment: Я запустил код, он печатает мне ключи, но если я хочу проверить если в ключе name есть имя alex или max то выдает false

Comment: @roman так проверяете? `if (i[key] == 'alex'):`

Comment: Работает спасибо ещё раз!